# Explanatory conditional evaluation, and monads?

Tags: macros, clojure, monads

I have a need for something like cond-> which returns the result along with those branches which evaluated true to give that result. Ideally it should be possible to use the explanatory part optionally only for testing and documentation, and have it be normal cond-> in use. I modified cond-> like this:

```
(defmacro explanatory-cond->
  "Adapted from Clojure's cond-> macro to keep a list of which conditions passed during evaluation"
  [expr & clauses]
  (assert (even? (count clauses)))
  (let [g (gensym)
        pstep
        (fn [[test step]]
          `(if ~test
            [(-> (if (vector? (first ~g)) (ffirst ~g) (first ~g)) ~step)
            (cons [(quote ~test) (quote ~step) (first ~g)] (second ~g))]
           ~g)
        )
       ]
    `(let [~g [~expr nil]
           ~@(interleave (repeat g) (map pstep (partition 2 clauses)))]
       ~g)))
```

which seems to work, but from my shallow knowledge of monads it looks like there might be a case for their use here (boxing and unboxing that vector) - could any gurus comment is this the case & if so, how to go about doing it, and if not is this modification of cond-> the way to go ?

Comment: It seems the specific monad your case resembles with is `Writer` monad. But I don't think that would make sense without a strong static type system like Haskell.

Comment: "Computations which produce a stream of data in addition to the computed values" - sounds great!

Comment: @Ankur actually, monads make sense, work well, and are quite useful in dynamic type systems as well.